# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable' after upgrading rxjs to 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-compat

I upgraded my Angular application from version 5.2 to 6.0 with the instructions from https://update.angular.io.

Now my Angular application doesn't build because of the "rxjs-5-to-6-migrate" migration:

> ERROR in bla.ts: error TS2339:
>   Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

I have the following imports:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

If I change the imports like this it works:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

But I don't understand why... I want to use the explicit imports and not import all operators.

---

**UPDATE:** As some answers pointed out I have to use pipes to be able to use operators. This was my problem because I thought I can still chain the operators to the observables.

*Old Style:*

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

this.http.get('/api/appsettings/get').map(data => { return true; }).catch(() => { return Observable.of(false); });
```

*New Style*

```
import { of,  Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get('/api/appsettings/get').pipe(map(data => { return true; }), catchError(() => { return of(false); }));
```

Comment: have you tried ``import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`` ?

Comment: try with `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `pipe` method on Observable and pass map function inside, like:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

of([1,2,3]).pipe(
  map(i => i*2)
);
```

Comment: This answer makes an additional important note about what OP will need to do moving forward _beyond_ just fixing the import.

Comment: Actually, this will work only until you have `rxjs-compat` installed. In RxJS 6 both `'rxjs/observable'` and `'rxjs/observable/of'` don't exist any more.

Comment: sure, fixed imports

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me to find my real problem.
I updated my question for other people to reflect my actual problem.

Answer (score 5):

Everything is explained here in the [RxJS v5.x to v6 Update Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#rxjs-v5x-to-v6-update-guide)

Import operators only from `'rxjs/operators'` and "creation" operators `'rxjs'`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Importing from `rxjs/Rx` works only because you added `rxjs-compat` package. You shouldn't use it after you upgrade to RxJS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Your imports should look like this now:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And you can't use `Observable.of`  you have to use `of()`

And you need to wrap any operator inside a `.pipe` like so:

```
.pipe(
     finalize(() => { this.isBusy = false; }),
     take(1),
     map(DATA => DATA.MESSAGEID)
)
```