# This property fromEvent does not exist on type 'typeof Observable' Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am having a problem trying to create to turn the **keyup** events into an observable stream.

I am following the Ng-book version 6.
I am stuck in an example that makes a search YouTube video as you type. When the search returns we’ll show a list of video thumbnail results, along with a description and link to each video.

So for this, we use an observable.fromEvent: https://github.com/NiLinli/ng-book2-angular-6-r68-code-samples/blob/master/http/src/app/you-tube-search/search-box.component.ts

In RxJS 5, it provides a way to listen to events on an element using Rx.Observable.fromEvent.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
// convert the `keyup` event into an observable stream
Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
```

But I am getting this error:

> ERROR in src/app/search-box/search-box.component.ts(42,13): error
>   TS2339: Property 'fromEvent' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   Observable'.

I RxJS 6 the import for Observable and fromEvent is like this:

```
import { Observable, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
```

This is my code for the RxJs5 version in Angular 6: (it doesnt work)

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
.map((e: any) => e.target.value) // extract the value of the input 
.filter((text: string) => text.length > 1) // filter out if empty 
.debounceTime(250) // only once every 250ms 
.do(() => this.loading.emit(true)) // enable loading
      // search, discarding old events if new input comes in
.map((query: string) => this.youtube.search(query)) 
.switch()
```

**This is my try with RxJs 6 and angular 6** (it's updated according with the last answer)

I am trying to use the pipe syntax:

```
    const obs = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .pipe (
            .map((e:any) => e.target.value) // extract the value of the input

            // .filter((text:string) => text.length > 1) //filter out if empty

            .debounceTime(250) //only search after 250 ms

            .tap(() => this.loading.emit(true)) // Enable loading
            // search, call the search service

            .map((query:string) => this.youtube.search(query)) 
            // discard old events if new input comes in

            .switchAll()
            // act on the return of the search
            )
```

But I have this error:

> Property 'map' doesnt exist on type Observable{<>}

And in the command line, after run ng serve:

> ERROR in search-box/search-box.component.ts(40,4): error TS1135: Argument > expression expected.
>   search-box/search-box.component.ts(54,4): error TS1128: Declaration or > statement expected.

But, it is not working... **So, how should I write my pipe sintax?**

How is my research going on:

1. The documentation from the Ng-book is outdated.
2. The documentation from the [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) is different.
3. I open an [Issue on GitHub,](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24167#issuecomment-392573591) but they send me back here

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable' after upgrading rxjs to 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412389/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable-after-upgrading-rxjs-to-6)

Comment: @IngoBürk But I am trying to import my `fromEvent` I dont have the problem with the `map` operator.  But thanks, I will check that answer.

Comment: how to mock fromEvent now in unit test?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This should work in your case :

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, debounceTime, tap, switchAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

  const obs = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .pipe (
        map((e:any) => e.target.value), // extract the value of the input

        // filter((text:string) => text.length > 1), //filter out if empty

        debounceTime(250), //only search after 250 ms

        tap(() => this.loading.emit(true)), // Enable loading
        // search, call the search service

        map((query:string) => this.youtube.search(query)) ,
        // discard old events if new input comes in

        switchAll()
        // act on the return of the search
        )
```

Hope it helps !

**EDIT**
Here is a working demo on Stackblitz: [Demo Angular 6 + Rxjs 6](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcv2ip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: it works for everything, except for `tab` and `switchall()` this is the error: `ERROR in search-box/search-box.component.ts(46,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'tap'.
search-box/search-box.component.ts(52,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'switchAll'.`

Comment: @ValRob I just added a demo to my answer. Check it out, it works juste fine!

Comment: how to mock fromEvent

Comment: And how do you unsuscribe to it in ngOnDestroy ?

Comment: Please add the imports

Answer (score 11):

In RxJS 5, you were writing

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

The imports changed for RxJS 6

```
import { Observable, of, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

For more information, have a look at the [RxJS migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md).

Comment: Sorry for bothering you @IngoBürk but I have a problem importing this. According with the documentation, I can import and wrap my operators inside a .pipe, but I still dont know how to fix this line: `Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')`  any idea? this is what give me the error: **Property 'fromEvent' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.**

Comment: @ValRob `import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';`  And then `const obs = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup');`

Comment: thanks @Pace, it works, but now I have a problem with the operators inside the .pipe, for example with the .map i got **Property `map`does not exist on type `Observable<{}>`**

Comment: Duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412389/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable-after-upgrading-rxjs-to-6)

Comment: How to stop the event of fromEvent in angular6??